# YouTube API: Embed my youtube channel on website. However, I'd like a specific video as the default video instead of the most recently uploaded video

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

YouTube API: Can I embed my youtube channel on a page on my site? However, I'd like a specific video as the default video instead of the most recently uploaded video.

I've tried: http://tcuttrissweb.wordpress.com/2012/02/17/2012-embed-your-youtube-channel-into-your-website

But that displays my most recent video as the default video. I'd like to display a specific video as the default.
Thank you.

Comment: It should be easy to do with the new YoutTube Data API v3. But what criteria you want to use to show the video?